# Is there a way to set a CORS header to a AWS signed URL?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, header, cors, aws-php-sdk

I am using a signed url from a GET object and the i could only find normal headers to use but not CORS headers. How do i make it possible so that content from another domain is accepted by the browser.I want to use a header like 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' and create a signed url.

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure CORS on your bucket. So it's not connected to your signed URL.

> When Amazon S3 receives a preflight request from a browser, it
>   evaluates the CORS configuration for the bucket and uses the first
>   CORSRule rule that matches the incoming browser request to enable a
>   cross-origin request.

Check the documentation for more informations: [How Do I Configure CORS on My Bucket?](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cors.html#how-do-i-enable-cors)